# Incorrect syntax near ' sys.objects '

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, jdbc

I am getting an Error Message saying

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'sys'.

And this often means that the SQL-query I've typed is wrong or I am missing a syntax. And I am very certain that this SQL-query I am using is right:

```
  public static Vector<Vector<String>> getKeys() throws SQLException {
    Vector<Vector<String>> vs = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
    Connection con = Dal2.getConnection();
    Statement stm = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rSet;
    String sqlString = "SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,"
            +"SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,"
            + "OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,"
            +"type_desc AS ConstraintType"
            +"FROM sys.objects"
            +"WHERE type_desc IN ('FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT','PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT')";

    try{
        rSet = stm.executeQuery(sqlString);
        while(rSet.next()){
            Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
            for(int i=1; i <= v.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(rSet.getString(i) + "\n");
         //                 v.add(rSet.getString(i));
            }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return vs;
```

As you can see I want to print out the SQL result-set on the Java console when I am using the method. But I keep getting syntax error. I've tried the SQL-query in SQL Server and it works fine:

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,
        SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName, 
        OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,
        type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type_desc IN ('FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT','PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT')
```

Comment: Insert space before `FROM` and `WHERE`.

Comment: Also, don't use `Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

The concatenated string looks like this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,type_desc AS ConstraintTypeFROM sys.objectsWHERE type_desc IN ('FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT','PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT')
```

Note the `ConstraintTypeFROM sys.objectsWHERE` part. It lacks spaces, causing SQL syntax error.

In general, it is a good idea to put a space at the end of each SQL line you concatenate into the final query. This way you wouldn't have to think about spaces at line breaks:

```
String sqlString = "SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint, " // <<== Space
        +"SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName, "                        // <<== Space
        + "OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName, "                 // <<== Space
        +"type_desc AS ConstraintType "                                  // <<== Space
        +"FROM sys.objects "                                             // <<== Space
        +"WHERE type_desc IN ('FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT','PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sqlString` is missing white-space characters in two places for your query

```
String sqlString = "SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,"
        + "SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName," 
        + "OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,"
        + "type_desc AS ConstraintType " // <-- here
        + "FROM sys.objects " // <-- here
        + "WHERE type_desc IN ('FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT','PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT')";
```

**tl;dr** Currently your query evaluates to (in part) `ConstraintTypeFROM sys.objectsWHERE`.